# Find $p$ such that $\mathbb{E}_p[v] = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to find probability distribution $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathbb{E}_p[v] = 0$. Meaning that,
find $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $p \geq 0, \sum_ip_i=1$ and
$$
p^Tv = 0
$$

1. Is there any closed form solution for $p$?
2. If not, is there any algorithm that can find such $p$?

Note: To make sure that there exists a solution for the problem, I'm assuming that $v$ has both positive and negative coordinates.

Comment: Any convex combination will do of which there are infinitely many.

Comment: This is not clear.  Do you just mean that you want an $n-$ vector $\vec p=(p_1,\cdots ,p_n)$ where the $p_i≥0$ and $\sum p_i=1$ such that $\vec p\cdot \vec v=0$?  What if $n=2$ and $\vec v=(1,1)$?  Or did you mean something else altogether?

Comment: Given that $\vec v$ has both positive and negative entries:  Just solve it in $\mathbb R^2$ (direct calculation).  Then pick one positive and one negative entry for $\vec v$ and apply the $\mathbb R^2$ solution to those two, setting all the other $p_i$ to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the related problem of finding all non-negative solutions $p$ to $p^T v = 1$ where $v$ is a vector with positive components.  Clearly $(1/v_1,0,0,...,0)$, $(0,1/v_2,0,...,0)$, ..., $(0,0,...,0,1/v_n)$ are solutions.  The set of all non-negative solutions $p$ is the convex hull of these fundamental solutions.

To solve your problem, let's rearrange the coordinates of $v$ to express it as $v = (v_+,v_0,v_-)$.  We can then take any solutions to $p_+^T v_+ = 1$ and $p_-^T (-v_-) = 1$, along with any non-negative vector $p_0$ and form $p = (p_+,p_0,p_-)$.  Normalizing this to sum to $1$ will give you the required probability distribution.  Indeed, this procedure describes the space of all possible probability vectors orthogonal to $v$ (well, almost:  we also have to include the case where $p_+$ and $p_-$ are zero, but $p_0$ is non-zero).